# Loading files and applying function to specific components in the code

Tags: r, list, filenames

I have a number of external files that I would like to load in that can be applied to my list `l1` based on the name of the list and the names of the files.

For example:
If I have 3 .csv files "2008.csv", "2009.csv", "2010.csv", and the data from these .csv files would be loaded in as a data frame. I would like to load in these data frames into the list as follows:

"2008.csv" into the first element in `l1` (i.e., 2008 in the list)

"2009.csv" into the second element in `l1` (2009 in the list)

"2010.csv" into the third element in `l1` (2010 in the list).

In this case, the .csv files are targeting specific elements of a list (i.e., "2009.csv" is not going into either 2008 and 2010.

Is there a way to tell R to look at the names of the files and load them into specific components of a list?

```
l1 <- list(NULL, NULL, NULL)
names(l1) <- c("2008", "2009", "2010")
```

Comment: Instead of creating a null list.  You may do this directly with `lapply` i.e. `files <- list.files(pattern = "^\\d{4}\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE); l1 <- setNames(lapply(files, read.csv), sub("\\.csv", "", basename(files)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution using `lapply` based on a user-supplied list of names:

```
lapply(c("2008", "2009", "2010"), function(thisfile) read.csv(paste0(thisfile, ".csv")))
```

(This is less sophisticated than akrun's suggestion in the comment, which searches over files and extracts the filename.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows :

```
l1 <- list()
list.names <- c("2008", "2009", "2010")
for(i in list.names){
  l1[[i]] <- read.csv2("file.csv", header=T)
}
```